# git: checkout or checkout-index a directory with a different name

Tags: git, git-checkout

I would like to checkout a directory, and its contents, from an earlier commit into the working directory under another name; or alternatively into another directory under the same name.

It's a bit like checking out a temp file, but I need a whole directory and I don't want to overwrite the existing one.

Comment: Have you tried doing a git clone to your new directory with a reference to the earlier commit?

Comment: is the content of the directory at the current revision fully under the source control? If so - you may simply checkout that directory from the earlier commit, rename it to the desired location and restore the state of the directory from the `HEAD`

Comment: The directory is currently under source control but is being used in a production web server so can't be rolled back to an earlier version even for a moment.

Comment: git clone sounds interesting, but I don't want to risk the .git data in the working directory. I guess I want the opposite of a bare repo in that I just want (part of) the working tree. Can you give an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging for more on this. In your situation, though, you will probably want to do the following:

```
 git read-tree -u --prefix=<temp-location>/ <old-commit>:<path/to/dir>
```

Comment: The man page synopsis for this needs improvement "Reads tree information into the index" didn't sound what I was looking for, but the `-u` is what I needed.